# Need to extract a specific url from source code in c# console

Tags: c#

Im making a bot that needs to display images from page links that are user fed. The only way i see of doing this is getting the href code from the source code

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("url that is input by the user");
                Console.WriteLine(htmlCode);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

is the current code that gets a url. If it helps, this query targets the card pages on the duelmaster wiki so the page layout is identical. I guess what im trying to ask is how do i get that code from the entire source code file?

Comment: So, what is your actual question?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be more specific. What is your question, where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract href data from a string

**Regular Expression :-**

> href[\s]*=[\s]*\"(.*?)[\s]*\"

**C# Code**

**Include namespace**

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

**Updated Code**

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Url you want to Extract data from");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    Task t = new Task(DownloadPageAsync);
    t.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Downloading page...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async void DownloadPageAsync(string requestUrl)
{
    // ... Use HttpClient instead of webclient
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl))
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
        string mydata = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Regex regex = new Regex("href[\\s]*=[\\s]*\"(.*?)[\\s]*\\\"");
        foreach (Match htmlPath in regex.Matches(mydata))
        {
            // Here you can write your custom logic
            Console.WriteLine(htmlPath.Groups[1].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Code explanation**

```
Regex regex = new Regex("href[\\s]*=[\\s]*\"(.*?)[\\s]*\\\"");
```

This line will create regex object with given regular expression

you can find regex explanation [Here](https://regex101.com/) after posting given regular expression

```
foreach (Match htmlPath in regex.Matches(mydata))
{
```

This line will iterate through all the matches found using regex in given string.

```
Console.WriteLine(htmlPath.Groups[1].Value);
```

**Notice (.*?) in regex its capture group**

Above line will give you your contains inside that group in your case data inside href brackets

Comment: What resources will i need to be using to use the Regex code?

Comment: jsut add using System.Text.RegularExpressions; in your code and you can use it

Comment: One more question, could you explain the code a bit, the syntax and all, im fairly new to this so would love to understand whats being done here for future uses

Comment: I think i get your code, but the thing is, the link(s) im trying to pull arent always the same, they change depending on the page name. 
If the user inputs 
https://duelmasters.wikia.com/wiki/Balesk_Baj,_the_Timeburner
i need the link "href=https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/duelmasters/images/7/74/BaleskBajtheTimeburner.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120522085136""
If the page is 
https://duelmasters.wikia.com/wiki/Aqua_Sniper
i need the link "href=https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/duelmasters/images/4/4d/AquaSniper.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20100917040743"
and so on, How would i do that?

Comment: Yea whatever link this will work, just pass your data in mydata, here  regex.Matches(mydata)) and foreach will do the trick

Comment: You dont get it, i dont have the url before hand, i need to get it after i get the input from the user using the source code i get from the link